# Cant post on facebook with release keystore

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

After Im created a release keystore in android studio, I'm generate a new release key hash(keytool -exportcert -alias YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS -keystore YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64) with my alias value, and my path to keystore and add it to facebook, I'm build a new release version in android studio and try to test it.

When I'm try to make a post on my wall:
            FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder((Activity) context)
                    .setPicture(imageUrl)
                    .setLink(imageUrl)
                    .build();
            uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());

When I press "Send", see toast with text "**Were sorry, this post is no longer available. It may have been removed**".

Why I can't post? Any ideas?

Thanks!